# Biblatex and CiteULike as a remote bib database

Tags: biblatex, biber

By reading the Biblatex package doc, I understand I can use my CiteULike bibliographic database as a resource, if only I specify the correct URL as a `remote` `databibresource`, and if I use `biber` as a `backend` (example in the doc: `\addbibresource[location=remote]{http://www.citeulike.org/bibtex/group/9517`, but no explanation on how to collect this URL for each one's needs).

The issue is thus to find the correct URL pointing to my personal CiteULike .bib database. I searched the Internet but could not find any answer, neither on the CiteULike website, nor in Biblatex tutorials.

Any idea on how to format/collect this URL?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here, since it essentially about features of CiteULike. A bit of googling reveals http://wiki.citeulike.org/index.php/Groups and https://www.overleaf.com/help/191-where-do-i-get-a-citeulike-group-id

Comment: You will probably only ever be able to make use of this feature for open groups though, private groups (obviously) need authentication with CiteULike which Biber may not be able to facilitate (that would depend on the methods used by CiteULike).

Comment: As the remote access to a CiteULike library is an example for a particular feature in the Biblatex package doc, I assumed this topic belonged to this group. My apologies if it does not.

Comment: Mhhh, it is a feature of Biber to be able to access remote sources and process those as `.bib` files. There is nothing particular about CiteULike. Did the advice about groups I googled together help?

Comment: @moewe: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helped very much. The remote access to a CiteULike library requires an open group to work indeed.

Comment: Does that mean your problem is solved?